# QThread sleeping on main thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4, sleep, simplify

I need to run QThread::usleep() on the main thread (for various reasons).
However, usleep is static protected.

I'd like to use QThread's usleep function without a wrapper (I'm currently using unistd.h 's usleep), to fully embrace Qt, but not add additional complexity to the code.

Is this possible? If so, what's the simplest (from point of view of a person reading the code) way to do so?

Comment: If you need to sleep, you should probably rethink your design. Qt's signal and slot is event driven and will usually do everything you need them to do.

Comment: +1 to @g19fanatic's comment, you can in most cases split your methods into chunks that you have invoked later

Comment: Your nebulous "various reasons" usually reduces to "I'm doing it wrong" - at least in case of a gui application. Had you shared your reasons, someone could point you how it should be done the right way. The GUI thread should never block. It's as simple as that. Anything else will lead to your users hating you, sooner or later.

Comment: my reasons are "my boss wants me to and I'm too lazy to explain why that's wrong to someone that doesn't know Qt"
either way, I need to stop something happening on the main thread that isn't usually supposed to be stopped (eliminating event-driven approaches).
As such I go into a semi-busy waiting using the event loop, semi-busy since I sleep in between.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to extend QThread and expose Xsleep methods as public:

```
class Sleeper : public QThread
{
public:
    static void usleep(unsigned long usecs){QThread::usleep(usecs);}
    static void msleep(unsigned long msecs){QThread::msleep(msecs);}
    static void sleep(unsigned long secs){QThread::sleep(secs);}
};
```

By the way. Qt5 changed QThread::Xsleep methods visibility to public.

Comment: +1 for Qt5 mention, since we will move to it eventually!
If no simpler/easier way is found you're definitively getting the answer (though it seems like such a shame to make a separate class for it~

Comment: I guess they changed it because of too many people [doing it wrong](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Comment: I'm moving from 5 to 4. I got the same issue since in Qt5 we've used static public methods.

Comment: Belated, but you don't need to redefine function. All you have to do is  put `using QThread::`-whatever-`sleep;` into public section